# Updating XML node with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I've an XML file test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<info>
  <user>
    <name>
      <firstname>FirstName</firstname>
      <lastname>Last Name</lastname>
      <nameCoordinate>
        <xName>125</xName>
        <yName>20</yName>
      </nameCoordinate>
    </name>
  </user>
</info>
```

I'm trying to update the node xName & yName using PHP on a form submission. So, I've loaded the file using simplexml_load_file(). The PHP form action code is below

```
<?php 
    $xPostName = $_POST['xName'];
    $yPostName = $_POST['yName'];

    //load xml file to edit
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    $xml->info->user->name->nameCoordinate->xName = $xPostName;
    $xml->info->user->name->nameCoordinate->yName = $yPostName;
    echo "done";
?>
```

I want to update the node values but the above code seems to be incorrect. Can anyone help me rectify it??

UPDATE:
My question is somewhat similar to this [Updating a XML file using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171539/updating-a-xml-file-using-php) but here, I'm loading the XML from an external file and also I'm updating an element, not an attribute. That's where my confusion lies.

Comment: what is not working as expected? you don't have an error explained.

Comment: I want to update the node values. It's not happening.

Comment: I've updated my question above.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're not accessing the right node. In your example, `$xml` holds the root node `<info/>`. Here's a great tip: **always name the variable that holds your XML document after its root node**, it will prevent such confusion.

Also, as Ward Muylaert pointed out, you need to save the file.

Here's the corrected example:

```
// load the document
// the root node is <info/> so we load it into $info
$info = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

// update
$info->user->name->nameCoordinate->xName = $xPostName;
$info->user->name->nameCoordinate->yName = $yPostName;

// save the updated document
$info->asXML('test.xml');
```

Comment: What will happen if the xName or yName node doesn't already exist?

Comment: What if you have several users with several yName and want to edit all of them at once? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You have to write the changes back to the file, use the [asXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) method of the SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: I believe that rewrites the whole tags. I want to update only specific nodes.

Comment: It does, but short of writing half the XML interpreting logic in your own code to only write specific nodes, I believe that is as far as you'll get with SimpleXML.

Answer (score 2):

try like this.

```
$xmlDoc = new \DOMDocument;
$xmlDoc->load('Books.xml');
$response = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('Text');

foreach ($response as $node){
        $node->nodeValue = 'test';
    }
$xmlDoc->saveXML();
```

this might not the best answer but it worked for me.