# Str Replace value in XML tag

Tags: php

I'd like to replace the value in this tag using PHP's ***str_replace*** function:

`<address2>Replace this value</address2>`

What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating XML node with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748014/updating-xml-node-with-php)

Comment: @KrzysztofRaciniewski Thanks for the reply. I'm not loading an XML file for this.  However, I have found this which looks handy: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.simplexml.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$nodeAdresseValue = str_replace("%value%", "your value", "<address2>%value%</address2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use string functions on XML, use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead, it'll help you parse XML more easily, here is an example code [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/h22b4):

```
<?php

$string = "<address2>Replace this value</address2>";
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadXML($string);
$address2Elements = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('address2');
foreach ($address2Elements as $address2) {
        $address2->nodeValue = "Value Replaced";

}

var_dump($domDocument->saveXML());
```

Output:

```
string(58) "<?xml version="1.0"?>
<address2>Value Replaced</address2>
"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search  = "/[^<address2>](.*)[^<\/address2>]/";
$replace = "replace with me";
$string  = "<address2>Replace this value </address2>";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$string);
```

this will work irrespective of the text, it will work even if you dont know the value inside tags